# Testing Android App build up with Jet Pack Compose with Appium UiAutomator2 Driver

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, appium, ui-automation

Our developers are using the latest standard for developing Android apps and use Jet Pack Compose Library.
Here you can not set typical resource ID as best locator strategy (https://www.browserstack.com/guide/locators-in-appium), while developers define testTags.
I did not want to change from UiAutomator2 driver to Espresso where there are solutions for this issue too.

My solution is to disable package name autocomplete with the help of disableIdLocatorAutocompletion settings api.

Like this:
desiredCapabilities.setCapability("disabledLocatorAutocompletion",true);
desiredCapabilities.setCapability("appiumVersion", "2.1.3"); //while this capability is implemented only from 2.0.6

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@resource-id='primary_button']"));

I use 2.1.3 as this is the next one after 2.0.6 supported by our cloud provider. This capability is supported only from 2.0.6: https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/10223
I use disabledLocatorAutocompletion from this discussion: https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/15138
I use this strange xpath instead of id strategy, while driver.findElement(By.id("primary_button")); does not work and id does not work according to: https://github.com/appium/python-client/issues/509#issuecomment-950604431

If someone find usefull this solution - feel free to use or even you can mayne advice how to do it better!